# visual studio skybound.gecko component disable right click?

Tags: vb.net, gecko

I'm designing a program with visual studio 2010 and I'm using skybound gecko component that is firefox 3.5 based web browser control.

I want to disable right click menu.

How can I disable or hide when I press right mouse button?

Thanks...

[this is the link what the problem is](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/257/24850385.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

Just Enable the NoDefaultContextMenu or just add a context